# How to do logical operation in Python dictionary?

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary.

```
dct = {'hello':1.9,'ciao':1.5,'yes':-2,'no':-3}
```

I would like to replace positive values with 1 and negative values with -1.

I tried many codes, one of which below:

```
 np.where(dct.values() > 0, 1, 0)
 np.where(dct.values() > 0, -1, 0)
```

However, it did not manage to make it work.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: would you mind using a for loop?

Comment: what about 0??? (Also changed your variable to `dct` as you should not overwrite the default `dict` class with your variable).

Comment: Post your code and ask questions about why it didn't work.

Comment: `dct = {k: 1 if v >= 0 else -1 for k,v in dct.items()}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could achieve this with a dict comprehension (not sure how you want to handle exactly equal to zero, if you expect that to occur)

```
>>> d = {'hello': 1.9,'ciao': 1.5,'yes': -2,'no': -3}
>>> {k: 1 if v > 0 else -1 for k, v in d.items()}
{'hello': 1, 'ciao': 1, 'yes': -1, 'no': -1}
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expression

```
1 if v >= 0 else -1
```

is maybe the most intelligible, but there are some shorter options :-)

```
(v >= 0) - (v < 0)

2 * (v >= 0) - 1

(1, -1)[v < 0]

from math import copysign as cs
cs(1, v)  # if you are ok with floats
```

just to list a few. Of course, all of them can plugged into the dict comprehension:

```
dct = {k: cs(1, v) for k, v in dct.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done using [`math.copysign`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) although is probably a bit overboard for a small application otherwise I would use what others have posted.

```
>>> from math import copysign
>>> {k: int(copysign(1, v)) for k, v in dct.items()}
{'hello': 1, 'ciao': 1, 'yes': -1, 'no': -1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

```
{k: 1 if v > 0 else -1 for k, v in dict.items()}
```

Do not use dict as variable name, by the way.

Comment: then why did you use it as such?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh
It was in the original post. I did it, so the reader would not be confused.

Comment: then please edit your answer so it would reflect it now, without the use of such variable name